# Swiper проблема с изменением slidesPerView

Tags: javascript, swiper

Инициализировал слайдер следующим образом:

```
this.slider = new Swiper('#calculator-slider-js', {
        navigation: {
            prevEl: '#calculator-slider-prev',
            nextEl: '#calculator-slider-next',
        },
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 2,
        breakpoints: {
            900: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
            },
            600: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
            },
        },

        observer: true
    });
```

Слайдер обновляется в зависимости от выбранного типа альбомов. Нужно сделать так, чтобы на альбомах одних типов показывалось 2 слайда на экране, а на других - 3 (если не действуют breakpoints). Делаю так:

```
if($this.albumType === albumTypes.BOOK || $this.albumType === albumTypes.FOLDER){
    $this.slider.params.slidesPerView = 3;
}else{
    $this.slider.params.slidesPerView = 2;
}
$this.slider.update();
```

На больших экранах всё норм, а вот на маленьких игнорируются breakpoints - показываются 2 или 3 слайда независимо от размера экрана. Причём breakpoints работают, если закомментировать эти строки. Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении slidesPerView не игнорировались breakpoints?